# How to batch commands?

Tags: linux, terminal

I'm pretty new in Linux shell, so I need help.

**WHAT I DO**
I'm developing a server side application and I use WinSCP to launch it. Everytime I have to stop and relaunch my app, I have to execute this commands in the WinSCP terminal:

1. pgrep -f Start.js, which gives me 2 IDs
2. kill -9 ID1, kill -9 ID2, to kill this processes
3. node Start.js, to restart the app

**WHAT I WOULD LIKE**
I have to execute this 3 commands manually, once by once. So: *is there a way to automate this procedure?*

Thanx.

Comment: Did you even *try* to do any research and solve this problem yourself?

Comment: If you need to send SIGKILL to terminate your server, then your server is broken.  Handle SIGTERM gracefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the commands into a script:

```
ids=($(pgrep -f Start.js))
kill -9 ${ids[0]}
kill -9 ${ids[1]}
node Start.js
```

Make it executable (chmod a+x restartjs.sh), put it into the path, call it when needed.

or into a function:

```
restartjs () {
    ids=($(pgrep -f Start.js))
    kill -9 ${ids[0]}
    kill -9 ${ids[1]}
    node Start.js
}
```

maybe into your ~/.bashrc and call it when needed.

But I don't know the winscp terminal - is it special?

`pkill -f` might be an option to simplify the program/function or `killall Start.js`.